# Ubuntu 14.04 "Check disk for errors" always returns 2 errors

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 on my system and no matter what I've tried I always get 2 errors on my bootable media. For reference. I checked the `md5sum` of my install, which worked. I tried creating the bootable drive using Universal USB Creator which gave me the 2 errors. I tried in both USB 2.0 and 3.0 slots on different computers with different drives. I then created the boot drive manually on my mac, still the same 2 errors found. These are all installs across different computers I checked out with `md5sum`, but no avail. I'm beginning to think there might be something wrong with the check for errors offered through ubuntu.

Anyone have any insight into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Universal USB Installer has a bug, use Unetbootin instead, Unetbootin is even specialized for Ubuntu.

https://unetbootin.github.io/

The iso file is OK if the checksums match.